# Form.is_valid no me funciona en Django 3

Tags: python, django, aplicación-web, django-forms

Estoy implementando el Login y register en Django y me aventuré a usa el usuario que viene por defecto, creando mi propio form para que el usuario logrará escribir el email, username, nombre, apellido y contraseña; mi problema es con el registro, ya que al tomar la información con el método POST, hago un if form.is_valid() pero ni siquiera entra y se va directo al else. Esta es mi funcion Register en el views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
       form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           usuario = form.save()
           usuario = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
           password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
           usuario = authenticate(username=usuario, password=password)
           login(request, usuario)
           return redirect("index")
       else:
           print("Error")


    form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, "auth/register.html", {"form": form})
```

Como ven, llamo al SignUpForm (que es mi form personal), el cual hice en un archivo forms.py:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username',
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    )
```

Y esta es mi register.html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="title">Sign Up</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
    </form>
    <p>Inicia sesión <a href="{% url 'login' %}">aquí</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

y mi ruta:

```
path('register/', views.register, name="register")
```

Al final, entro a mi ventana de registro, lleno los datos y al dar en ingresar, me redirige nuevamente a register.html y en la terminal me imprime Error, como lo especifique con el else

Comment: Es difícil saber si no se conocen los campos del modelo **User**. Por lo menos el que provee Django  `django.contrib.auth.User` solo tiene un campo para **password**, no dos como aparece en el código de arriba.

Comment: Con respecto a la manera en que estructure todo, esta linea:  `form = SignUpForm(request.POST)` es correcta? soy nuevo en Django, por cierto XD

Comment: Sí es correcto. Y **form.cleaned_data** es un diccionario con los datos normalizados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He comprobado tu código y a mi me redirecciona al indice sin ningún problema.

#### respuesta rápida

Te esta saliendo Error porque `form.is_valid()` es `Falso`.

El código esta siguiendo la lógica programada.

Esto es debido a que pones un password que no cumple los requisitos, o email incorrecto.

#### propuesta de camino

Te propongo dos caminos a seguir para tu necesidad.

1. Utilizar la vista [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

   Es la vista por defecto que lleva `Django`. Código optimizado, comprobado, minimizado, el recomendado vaya.

   #### inconvenientes

   El problema es que si utilizas esta vista, no vas a profundizar en código.

   E intentar a entender la clase LoginView de buenas a primera es difícil, ya que hay mucho procedimiento interno de `Django` y de herencia de clases.

   #### ventajas

   Es muy rápida de implementar, solo en el fichero de `urls.py`

   ```
   path('accounts/login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html'))
   ```

   Y rellenar tu plantilla `myapp/login.html` a tu gusto, y a funcionar!
2. Buscar un código entremedio, por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805635/after-authentication-its-not-redirecting-to-next-page-in-django) te valdría, y te ayudará a entender todo el proceso. Puedes compararlo con el tuyo y hacer limpieza.

Comment: Ciertamente si redirecciona al index, lo que hice fue eliminar el sqlite y correr de nuevo las migraciones y así funciono, fue algo muy raro, sin embargo ayer que les mostraba el codigo a mis amigos, nuevamente no funciono, y despues de varios intentos, de diferentes pruebas con diferentes usuarios me di cuenta que existe algun problema de concurrencia (ya que tengo abierto el db browser y a veces hago cambios ahí) en fin, que el problema parece ser otro, seguire investigando y si tengo que cambiar esto que hice, pues lo cambio, muchas gracias por la respuesta